# Why is this function differentiable?

Tags: calculus

I know that the piecewise function $ f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       2x & , x < 1\\
       x+1 & , x \geq 1
     \end{array}
   \right. $
is differentiable because $2x$ and $x + 1$ converge at different rates based on their slope but why is $
f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{x^2-1}{x-1} & , x \neq 1\\
       2 & , x=1
     \end{array}
   \right.
$ differentiable? I know that it is continuous but their slopes are different.

Thanks!

Comment: Your second $f$ is the same as $x\mapsto x+1$ which is clearly differentiable everywhere.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}2x&\text{if }x<1\\x+1&\text{if }x\ge1\end{array}\right.$ is *not* differentiable at $x=1$. $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't be tricked by the seemingly complicated piecewise definition of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,
$$
f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{x^2-1}{x-1} & , x \neq 1\\
       2 & , x=1.
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
It is exactly the same function as $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=x+1$, since
$$
\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}=x+1=g(x) & , x \neq 1\\
       2 = 1+1 = x+1 = g(x)& , x=1.
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
Obviously the function $g$ is differentiable everywhere, and hence $f$ is too, since they are the one and same.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks! I got stuck there for a while.